# How to make Gedit an IDE?

Tags: gedit, programming, ide

I just want to do all my coding stuff at one place. So I am interested to make my Gedit a universal IDE. It should support at least C, C++, Java, Python, JavaScript and Markup Language.

Answer (score 3):

Imho GEdit is far from being an ideal base for an IDE. You would be better off with an actual IDE like [Eclipse](//www.eclipse.org) and its various plug-ins.

In my experience it's also better to use IDEs specialized to a particular language, task set, or framework like [JetBrains](//www.jetbrains.com)' [IDEA](//www.jetbrains.com/idea/) (Java), [PyCharm](//www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) (Python), [WebStorm](//www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) (JavaScript, non-free), and [CLion](//www.jetbrains.com/clion/) (C/C++, non-free) – they all have very similar user interfaces in case you're worried about that. [Qt Creator](//www.qt.io/IDE/) is an excellent fully open-source alternative for C/C++/QML development.

If you really want to start with a text editor as a base and enhance it with developer features go with something highly customizable like [Atom](//www.atom.io), [Sublime Text](//www.sublimetext.com), or [Emacs](//apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/emacs/) and their various plug-ins and extensions. While GEdit is very customizable itself the existing supply of useful, up-to-date plug-ins is far smaller than for the other three.

Comment: Great advice. +1

Answer (score 2):

gedit supports syntax highlighting for all these languages out of the box, and will usually auto-detect the syntax mode when each file is opened.

If you want to make it feel more like a heavyweight editor, turn on the side panel (view->side panel), set it to file browser mode, and use this to switch between the files in your project directory.

If you go to the preferences dialog, a lot of the syntax and indentation options are in there.

There's also an external tools plugin that you can enable for functionality like building from a makefile within the editor environment. I can't vouch for how useful this functionality is; I prefer to build from a separate terminal window so I wouldn't personally want to invest time into setting up that level of integration - but that's my own preference.

While it's true that gedit doesn't have as many plugins as editors like Visual Studio Code and Atom, it's still a fast and solid editor (the two I just mentioned have some wonderful features if you invest the time in customising them, but they've also let me down a few times in terms of startup performance, unwanted distractions, and even just maintaining file integrity when running in multiple windows; to the point that I no longer trust them as basic editors.) and a good fraction of the fundamentals are there. I would certainly recommend gedit as an entry-level code editor; at least until you develop a feel for what kinds of other functionality you're after.

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak some thing in gedit to make "programmer friendly" by going to preferences, then in the "view" tab you can enable: 
 - Display line numbers
 - Display status bar
 - Highlight Current line
 - Highlight matching brackets

Then, in the "Plugins" tab you can select the plugins that you need.
Also, when you go back to the editor you will notice that there's a text in the bottom of the screen that says "Plain Text", click it and you will be able to change the language that you are working on.

You can compile your code using the terminal, there are several tutorials on the internet of how to do this, every language is diferent.

For example, for python you can just type:

```
python <filename.py>
```

For java you must type:

```
javac <filename.java>
```

and then...

```
java <filename>
```

Hope my explanation can be useful for you, Good luck!